# Understanding union query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if someone can explain this to me and would be great if I can also get a source for it.

```
USE AP;

SELECT VendorName, VendorState
FROM Vendors
WHERE VendorState = 'CA'
UNION
SELECT VendorName, 'Outside CA'
FROM Vendors
WHERE VendorState <> 'CA'
Order BY VendorName
```

I can almost explain this in English, I know this query is saying

Select VendorName and VendorState from Vendors table
Show all vendorStates that are in California
join with

And this is where I get confused:

`Select vendorName, 'outside CA'` --Other than 'Outside Ca' being a string what else is it, is it a variable? And how does it know to replace the state value with 'Outside Ca' if vendorState value is not California.

Comment: This particular example is inefficient and does not need `union` at all, and could be expressed much simpler `SELECT VendorName, CASE WHEN VendorState = 'CA' THEN VendorState ELSE 'Outside CA' END AS VendorState FROM Vendors Order BY VendorName;`. Furthermore, even when using `union`, consider using `union all` instead, as `union` forces de-duplication (`distinct`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 factors coming into play here:

1. `UNION` adds multiple resultsets together (two in this case) i.e. takes the rows returned from multiple queries and combines them into a single resultset. As an aside you should use `UNION ALL` because it performs better. Note union is not a join and has nothing in common with a join. Joins are horizontal, unions are vertical. All queries in a union must have the same number columns with the same datatype. However you only need to alias the columns in the first query. I have aliased the second below so it can be run without the union.
2. You can select static data as part of a query. `'Outside CA'` is static, i.e. is returned as that for every row in that query, because as you have noted, we are excluding CA in that query.

So you have 2 queries, the first is for state CA and the second is for states not CA, and for the second query instead of showing the state, it is showing the static value 'Outside CA'. These 2 queries are unioned together to give a single resultset.

The best way to understand is to create an example - I highly recommend this for your future understanding e.g.

```
DECLARE @Vendors TABLE (VendorName VARCHAR(32), VendorState CHAR(2));

INSERT INTO @Vendors (VendorName, VendorState)
VALUES 
('Test 1','CA'),
('Test 2','CA'),
('Test 3','NY'),
('Test 4','NY');

SELECT VendorName, VendorState
FROM @Vendors
WHERE VendorState = 'CA'
UNION ALL
SELECT VendorName, 'Outside CA' VendorState
FROM @Vendors
WHERE VendorState <> 'CA'
ORDER BY VendorName;
```

If you remove the union you get the results from the 2 queries e.g.

| VendorName | VendorState |
| --- | --- |
| Test 1 | CA |
| Test 2 | CA |

| VendorName | VendorState |
| --- | --- |
| Test 3 | Outside CA |
| Test 4 | Outside CA |

Then add back the union and you get see the effect:

| VendorName | VendorState |
| --- | --- |
| Test 1 | CA |
| Test 2 | CA |
| Test 3 | Outside CA |
| Test 4 | Outside CA |

Comment: Thank you so much!, makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: I just learned more in this very post than the whole chapter, is there any sources you recommend?

Comment: @EGAM sorry no, not at this level, just find tutorials out there and see if they help.

Comment: awesome, now that I know what to look for should be easy thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As what others have said, [`UNION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Concatenates the results of two queries into a single result set. You control whether the result set includes duplicate rows:
>
> - UNION ALL - Includes duplicates.
> - UNION - Excludes duplicates.
>
> A UNION operation is different from a JOIN:
>
> A UNION concatenates result sets from two queries. But a UNION does
> not create individual rows from columns gathered from two tables. A
> JOIN compares columns from two tables, to create result rows composed
> of columns from two tables. The following are basic rules for
> combining the result sets of two queries by using UNION:
>
> The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all
> queries.
>
> The data types must be compatible.

Let's say you have these values in your table:

[image: sample table]

In your query, the first result set is:

```
SELECT VendorName, VendorState
FROM Vendors
WHERE VendorState = 'CA'
```

This gives you something like:

[image: result set 1]

Then the 2nd result set

```
SELECT VendorName, 'Outside CA'
FROM Vendors
WHERE VendorState <> 'CA'
```

would give you:

[image: result set 2]

`UNION` combines those 2 result sets into one with `ORDER BY VendorName`

[image: UNION]

So basically, what you did here is select vendor names in your table then substitute the `VendorState` into `'Outside CA'` if they are not `CA`.

The string `'Outside CA'` is static, which means, all rows in your `SELECT` statement will return `'Outside CA'` for that column.

You could use [`CASE` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead to achieve similar results:

```
SELECT 
    VendorName
    , CASE
        WHEN VendorState <> 'CA' THEN 'Outside CA'
        ELSE 'CA'
    END
FROM #temp1
Order BY VendorName
```

Comment: case is an *expression* not a *statement* :) also formatted text is much preferred over images on SO.\

Answer (score -1):

The bit that is confusing you is the UNION clause.  It essentially joins 2 different selects into one set of results.

You can have a look at the MySQL manual for a technical explanation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html or for a simpler explanation try the dredded [w3school explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: Or SQL Server since thats what OP is asking.

Comment: Thanks guys Checking those out right now.